# Light Theme app with Dark Theme RecyclerView

Tags: android

I have a Light theme app and in one of the screens I have a recycler view that I need to be dark.

I have tried setting the theme of the recyclerview to "@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" but the RecyclerView stays with same background color, only the text shows up as white on the preview, but on the real device it stills shows as dark (and thus if I put a background it cannot be read).

This is the item layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              style="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
              android:padding="@dimen/single_padding"
              android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="52''"
        style="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        tools:text="52''"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/single_padding"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="Title"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="Subtitle"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is how i declare my recyclerview:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/highlights_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:listitem="@layout/highlight_list_item"/>
```

Comment: manually set `android.textColor="#ffffff"` for TextView

Comment: try something along the lines of recyclerView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));